# Python. Ошибка при наложении двух фото через PIL

Tags: python, pil

```
img = Image.open('files/img/bg.png')

ava = Image.open('files/img/ava_user.png')

img.paste(ava, (230, 230), ava)
img.save("/files/img/cit_comp")
```

Ошибка:

> `bad transparency mask`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273592/valueerror-bad-transparency-mask-when-pasting-one-image-onto-another-with-pyt

Answer (score 1):

```
img = Image.open('files/img/bg.png').convert("RGBA")

ava = Image.open('files/img/ava_user.png').convert("RGBA")

img.paste(ava, (230, 230), ava)
img.save("/files/img/cit_comp")
```